# Get data for AJAX tooltip from URL adress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using this [script](http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/ajaxtooltip.shtml) for tooltips. 
Is there any way to load content of tooltip from URL(dynamic loaded content from PHP script) instead of using path to html/php file?

**Example**

I need this:

```
<a href="#" title="ajax:http://localhost/site/getcontent/1">Some link</a>
```

instead of:

```
<a href="#" title="ajax:/site/content_1.html">Some link</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a brief look at the plugin, and you should be able to use `/site/getcontent/1` without any issue.

```
<a href="#" title="ajax:/site/getcontent/1">Some link</a>
```

(I'm assuming is being loaded on the same domain of your html file)